# Android Camera2 + MediaCodec + MediaMuxer using persistent surface?

Tags: android, video-capture, android-camera2, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

I'm writing a video camera app. When I open my capture activity I would like to configure a camera capture session that starts a preview, and when the user later presses the record button it should start recording video using MediaCodec + MediaMuxer (not MediaRecorder for app-specific reasons) *without* having to recreate a new CameraCaptureSession. I tried using [MediaCodec#createPersistentInputSurface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec#createPersistentInputSurface()) to make this possible.

So far I have got the preview working and the MediaCodec/MediaMuxer bit is producing a 'valid' output video file (as per ffprobe), but the content of the video is flashes of random diagonal colours/scrambled. On another device the same code fails to create the capture session at all. I believe the problem is that I am creating the MediaCodec instance **after** creating the capture session, meaning that when the camera is configured with the persistent surface it has no idea what output size and colour format it should be using.

*My question: What pipeline do I need to follow in order to achieve the behaviour I'm looking for with MediaCodec and a persistent input surface?*

**My notes:**

- As far as I've tested/understood, you can only use a MediaCodec instance once. For the next recording you have to create a new one. So to have only a single camera capture session that allows multiple video recordings, creating a MediaCodec instance *after* configuring the capture session is required.
- The same surface must be used for all created MediaCodecs because it is specified in the camera capture session (can [deferred surfaces (second bullet point)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/OutputConfiguration) change this?), hence why it needs to be persistent.
- The persistent surface needs to be created before the camera capture session, and the MediaCodec would need to configure the persistent surface before the camera capture session is started...

A bit of a chicken and the egg problem. Is there a way to break this cyclic dependency loop?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up getting the required behaviour (even if it seems a bit hacky) by doing the following:

- Create the persistent input surface
- Create a dummy MediaCodec with exactly the same configuration/parameters as you will later be recording with, going as far as calling `MediaCodec::configure` and `MediaCodec::setInputSurface` (with the persistent input surface). This initialises the persistent surface's internal color/format parameters etc, which is required for creating the capture session to succeed.
- Create the required capture session with the persistent input surface
- Release the dummy video encoder as we don't need it anymore

From there on, you can keep the one same camera capture session and create new MediaCodecs every time you want to record something, but they always need to be configured exactly like the dummy one was, otherwise there could be recording issues.

*Side-note:* In the question I thought deferred surfaces could help, but I fully understand them now, and no, they don't help with that specific problem.

Comment: Thanks!  How did you handle the persistent surface when you weren't also recording a video file?  Did you just create a different capture request that only included your preview surface (and not the persistent surface for recording)?  Or did you include both in your capture request but have the persistent surface hooked to a dummy MediaCodec thats always churning through the data and getting / releasing the output buffer and throwing it away?  I am assuming the first?  Any suggestions on how you managed capture requests with this?

Comment: @Matt I had different requests with different surfaces. In my case I had to be able to support constantly changing requests anyway because I implemented my own exposure controller. I recall it was a lot of very careful work to keep track of all the requests that had been made, and when they were truly complete etc, even if they were set as repeating. Btw I had a request builder that I added/removed target surfaces from and then called build() on to get the appropriate requests.

Comment: Thanks, I am assuming you didn't find a way to change the resolution without starting a new camera session?  I tried configuring a bunch of different persistent surfaces for the initial session which I could select between on the request but that didn't work :)

Comment: @Matt I didn't look so hard into that because in my case the user has to open a menu to change the resolution, which would require a camera session restart anyway. But I think you're right